# separating a string into new columns if a part is found

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column that contains multiple values of interest. I would like to break it apart into many parts.

```
s = ['FEW:02 24 BKN:05 35 SCT:04 50', 'FEW:02 24 BKN:05 45']
```

The ideal format would look something like this:

```
     FEW_OKTA  FEW_ELEVATION  BKN_OKTA  BKN_ELEVATION  SCT_OKTA  SCT_ELEVATION 
 1:  02        24             05        35             04        50
 2:  02        24             05        45             0         0
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Pandas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really unique question , I can only provide the solution for the sample in Op .

```
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(s).str.split(' |:').values.tolist())
new_df=df.loc[:,df.columns%3!=0]
new_df
Out[120]: 
    1   2   4   5     7     8
0  02  24  05  35    04    50
1  02  24  05  45  None  None
helpdf=df.loc[:,df.columns%3==0]
new_df.columns=helpdf.iloc[0].tolist()*2

new_df.columns=new_df.columns+'_'+pd.Series(['OKTA','ELEVATION']*(new_df.shape[1]//2))
new_df
Out[128]: 
  FEW_OKTA BKN_ELEVATION SCT_OKTA FEW_ELEVATION BKN_OKTA SCT_ELEVATION
0       02            24       05            35       04            50
1       02            24       05            45     None          None
```